# What do the multiple brown arrows in a grounding diagram indicate?

Tags: grounding

I'm curious to know what the multiple brown arrows in this grounding diagram refer to?  I don't think they refer to grounding rods, but would you have any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the leftward pointing arrows on the top right of the diagram?

Comment: I don't think that is a standard symbol. Probably indicates that there are many other connections to that bar, or that it is distribution of some sort.

Comment: Looks like bonding connections from chassis to ground.